# Set property only if is not null

Tags: java

I have some data in input that I'll have to use to set all properties of a POJO. The POJO might be partially set. My problem is to set the property only if related input data is not null.
I know I can do this in two ways:

```
if (input != null) {
    obj.setData(input);
}
```

or

```
obj.setData(input != null ? input : obj.getData());
```

I'm looking for a solution less ugly and better for objects with a big number of properties to set.

Comment: Well, in order to check for null you have to check for null :-)

Comment: I searched similar questions before posting, and I've not found this. Maybe is different. My problem is to not overwrite existing data in a pojo with a null value. Because my not long experience with java (I started to use it 1 year and some months ago), I hoped for the existence of a better way to do this.

Answer (score 17):

You can also use `java8` [Optional](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html)

```
obj.setData(Optional.ofNullable(input).orElse(obj.getData()));
```

Or even use a more elegant way:

```
Optional.ofNullable(input).ifPresent(obj::setData);
```

Comment: Thanks, but I can't use java 8. I must use java 7.

Comment: As for me in this case null checking must be inside of the setter.

Comment: In Java 7 you can use Optional from Guava

Answer (score 0):

Use guava:

```
String someString = "value";
Optional.fromNullable(someString).or("defaultValue");
```